# Post form with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Start learning Ajax (and jQuery), I encounter the issue with post form data, which I could not resolve myself.

First, here is the simple example where I collect data, post it, and displayed it on a new page:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="Ch1" value="1">Check Box 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="Ch2" value="2">Check Box 2 <br />
<input type="submit" id="myButton" />
</form>

<?php
// test.php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Then I tried with Ajax and jQuery. I slightly modified the form pasted above:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<form id="myForm"> 
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="Ch1" value="1">Check Box 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="Ch2" value="2">Check Box 2 <br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery function:

```
// script.js

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: $("#myForm").serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

My question is, how to reimplement the jQuery function to echo the result in the `test.php` tab? I crawled the many resources, but i didn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Best, Andrej

Comment: What "tab"? test.php is your target script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `success` in the `.ajax` options parameter.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(d){
    alert(d);
  }
});
```

Comment: But this will show just an alert message. What I want is to open test.php and render the result there.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of AJAX then. If you're looking for the window to open, AJAX is not you're bet. AJAX is used for a "seamless integration", perform duties without leaving the page. For what you're trying to do I recommend using the default form action (and maybe adding a `target="_blank"` so it submits in a new window.

Comment: Alright, good. Got confused by the way you worded it. Now, just bind it to an element (like `<div id="myElement"></div>`) and place the results there using something like `$('#myElement').html(d);` (in place of the alert).

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a `success` callback, which I'll assume will be some HTML...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#someElement").html(response);
        }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: But this will show the $_POST in my index.html. What I want is to open test.php and render the result there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
        });
    }); 
});
```